# T-test between vectors subseted from the data frame

Tags: r

I would like to perform the `t.test` to get the `pvalue` between specified vectors. Let's use the data below as an example:

```
structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 
                       24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32.4, 
                       30.4, 33.9, 21.5, 15.5, 15.2, 13.3, 19.2, 27.3, 26, 30.4, 15.8, 
                       19.7, 15, 21.4), cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 
                                                8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4), 
               disp = c(160, 160, 108, 258, 360, 225, 360, 146.7, 140.8, 
                        167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472, 460, 440, 78.7, 75.7, 
                        71.1, 120.1, 318, 304, 350, 400, 79, 120.3, 95.1, 351, 145, 
                        301, 121), hp = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 
                                          123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 
                                          150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175, 335, 109), drat = c(3.9, 
                                                                                                    3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 
                                                                                                    3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 2.93, 3, 3.23, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22, 3.7, 2.76, 
                                                                                                    3.15, 3.73, 3.08, 4.08, 4.43, 3.77, 4.22, 3.62, 3.54, 4.11
                                          ), wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 
                                                    3.15, 3.44, 3.44, 4.07, 3.73, 3.78, 5.25, 5.424, 5.345, 2.2, 
                                                    1.615, 1.835, 2.465, 3.52, 3.435, 3.84, 3.845, 1.935, 2.14, 
                                                    1.513, 3.17, 2.77, 3.57, 2.78), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 
                                                                                             19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20, 22.9, 18.3, 18.9, 17.4, 17.6, 
                                                                                             18, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42, 19.47, 18.52, 19.9, 20.01, 16.87, 
                                                                                             17.3, 15.41, 17.05, 18.9, 16.7, 16.9, 14.5, 15.5, 14.6, 18.6
                                                    ), vs = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                              0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), am = c(1, 
                                                                                                                      1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gear = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 
                                                                                                                                                                    3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                                                                                                                                    3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4), carb = c("M_PP", "O_PP", "C_PP", "K_MM", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         "T_MM", "C_MM", "R_PP", "E_PP", "W_PP", "Q_PP", "R_MM", "T_MM", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         "V_MM", "Q_MM", "F_PP", "D_PP", "S_PP", "Z_PP", "K_PP", "G_PP", "F_MM", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         "D_MM", "S_MM", "Z_MM", "K_MM", "F_MM", "A_PP", "D_PP", "T_PP", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         "R_MM", "D_MM", "T_MM"), Name = c("Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "Mark", "Mark", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "Tom", "Tom", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "Greg", "Greg", "Greg")), .Names = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb", "Name"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below you can just see one group which can be distinguished from this data frame:

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb Name
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4 M_PP Mark
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4 O_PP Mark
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4 C_PP Mark
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3 K_MM Mark
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3 T_MM Mark
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3 C_MM Mark
```

So, I would like to perform the `t.test` between the `PP` and `MM` - subgroups of Mark (`carb` column). The column which is interesting for me is `gear`. I would like to know that difference in gears number is statistically important withing those subgroups.

Such analysis should be performed for all the groups like `Mark` from this data.

The results (pvalues) can be stored in the same  data frame in additional column. It means that pvalues will be repeated in all the rows belonging to the same group.

Comment: What have you tried already? And how do you want to handle the M /O / C... prefixes?

Comment: I tried to do it in loop by using function `grep1`. Unfortunately I can't say that's working for whole data because it is too big data for my computer to handle it in loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite straight forward when using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(carb1 = gsub('.*_', '', carb), p_values = t.test(cyl[carb1 == 'PP'], cyl[carb1 == 'MM'])$p.value) %>% 
  select(-carb1)

#Source: local data frame [32 x 13]
#Groups: Name [4]

#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  Name  p_values
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#1   21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4  M_PP  Mark 0.2301996
#2   21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4  O_PP  Mark 0.2301996
#3   22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4  C_PP  Mark 0.2301996
#4   21.4     6 258.0   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3  K_MM  Mark 0.2301996
#5   18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3  T_MM  Mark 0.2301996
#6   18.1     6 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3  C_MM  Mark 0.2301996
#7   14.3     8 360.0   245  3.21 3.570 15.84     0     0     3  R_PP   Tom 0.1294094
#8   24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4  E_PP   Tom 0.1294094
#9   22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4  W_PP   Tom 0.1294094
#10  19.2     6 167.6   123  3.92 3.440 18.30     1     0     4  Q_PP   Tom 0.1294094
```

**NOTE:** I used `cyl` as `gear` throws the error

> Error: data are essentially constant

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use `cyl` instead of `gear`, because `t.test` throws a "data are essentially constant" error when I use `gear`.  Suppose the data is an object named `d`.

We proceed in several steps.

1. We split up the dataframe by `Name`, through `split(d, d$Name)`.
2. We create a new variable `group` using the `carb` suffixes.
3. We do a `t.test` for `cyl` within the subset.

   ```
   D <- lapply(split(d, d$Name), function(x) {
          x$group <- factor(gsub(".*(PP|MM)", "\\1", x$carb))
          t.test(x$cyl[x$group=="PP"], x$cyl[x$group=="MM"])$p.value
        })
   ```

The output so far:

```
D
# $Greg
# [1] 0.7250302

# $Mark
# [1] 0.2301996

# $Tim
# [1] 0.5995106

# $Tom
# [1] 0.1294094
```

We finish by reshaping `D` into a dataframe, and merging it with our original dataframe:

```
D <- data.frame(Name = names(D),
                pvalue = unlist(D))
merge(d, D)
#    Name  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am        gear carb    pvalue
# 1  Greg 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1  0.37495820 A_PP 0.7250302
# 2  Greg 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1 -2.07140903 D_PP 0.7250302
# 3  Greg 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1 -0.73900855 T_PP 0.7250302
# 4  Greg 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1 -0.09174744 R_MM 0.7250302
# 5  Greg 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1 -1.55889142 D_MM 0.7250302
# 6  Greg 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1  0.78601261 T_MM 0.7250302
# 7  Mark 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1  1.60209096 M_PP 0.2301996
# 8  Mark 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1  0.25393125 O_PP 0.2301996
# 9  Mark 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1 -1.14837484 C_PP 0.2301996
# 10 Mark 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0  0.68440881 K_MM 0.2301996
# 11 Mark 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0 -1.04994050 T_MM 0.2301996
# 12 Mark 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0 -2.18665934 C_MM 0.2301996
# ..snip..
```